# How to get all the combinations for an array of a specific length

Tags: javascript, node.js, combinations

Let's say I have this array of characters I want to use:

```js
var acceptableCharacters = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

I'd like to get all possible combinations of this array, say from a length of `2` to `4`, so the output might look something like this

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ba
bb
bc
bd
ca
cb
cc
cd
da
db
dc
dd
```

...And so on...

The generator should be able to meet these conditions:

- Aims for all combinations between 2 lengths, or allows itself to accept any different length
- Letters can repeat themself

I'm not really sure where to start, so some starter code would be nice.

edit:

```js
    var characters = ['a','b','c','d'];
    var combinations = [];
    for(var i=2;i<=4;i++) {
        var str = "";
        for(var c of characters) {
            str+=c;
            // 'a' spam
        }
        combinations.push(str);
    };
    console.log( combinations );
```

I don't know how to iterate the characters ¯_(ツ)_/¯

It looks like this:

```
ab
abc
abcd
```

Comment: edited not even sure what to call this besides 'all possible combinations of an array',

Comment: If you want to code well then why don't you study for loop from start? Or if you want to know how to get iterate combination of arrays then googling will be easy to get an answer you want.

Comment: Hey have a look at the python standard library itertools. It contains a [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.combinations) generator implementation that does exactly what you want. Try to understand the algorithm and then implement it in your language of choice.:)

Comment: @jacobkim It's hard to know what to google for if you don't know what your problem is called.  @ the close votes: This is a pretty well written question; it shows research, explains the problem and desired effect, and (perhaps after the edits) is well formatted... I've tried to find a duplicate on SO, but couldn't find it. If OP implements the algorithm in an answer, it will make a good SO post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I see with your code is that you need a nested loop for each additional combination length, i.e. for length 2 you need a double-nested iteration, for length 3 a triple-nested iteration, and so on.

Took a stab at an implementation using recursion. It recurses down to the base case of length 1 and builds up the result set.

```js
const characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

const combinations = (arr, min = 1, max) => {
  const combination = (arr, depth) => {
    if (depth === 1) {
      return arr;
    } else {
      const result = combination(arr, depth - 1).flatMap((val) =>
        arr.map((char) => val + char)
      );
      return arr.concat(result);
    }
  };

  return combination(arr, max).filter((val) => val.length >= min);
};

const result = combinations(characters, 2, 4);

console.log(`Combinations: ${result.length}`, result);
```

Here's a non-recursive version; it ended up being a bit simpler.

```js
const characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

const combinations = (arr, min = 1, max) =>
  [...Array(max).keys()]
    .reduce(
      (result) =>
        arr.concat(result.flatMap((val) => arr.map((char) => val + char))),
      []
    )
    .filter((val) => val.length >= min);

const result = combinations(characters, 2, 4);

console.log(`Combinations: ${result.length}`, result);
```